# Check if only one button is not clicked in C#

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in C# so bear with me.
I'm creating a board game in C# but I have a problem.
The game looks like this:
[Solo Board game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xnxm.png)

> The two white dots are your start position. The goal of the game is to fill the board with the white dots, but only one dot remains black.

**My question is:** How to check if all the buttons are white and only one is black?

The code is not very optimized. The Form1 class is for the form, The Stone class is for all the dots and the Win form class is for the form when you win the game.

Code Form1 class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Solo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Objects
        public Stone[] st = new Stone[41];
        int[] x = { 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 150, 200, 250, 200 };
        int[] y = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 250, 250, 250, 300 };

        bool cl = true;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int a = 0; a < 41; a++)
            {
                st[a] = new Stone();
            }

            st[12].getPen().Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            st[13].getPen().Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            st[0].setClick(cl);
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs a)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < st.Length; i++)
            {
                st[i].setLocation(x[i], y[i]);
                st[i].Click += new EventHandler(st[i].stone_Click);

                this.Controls.Add(st[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code Stone class:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Solo
{
    public class Stone : Button
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 19);

        bool clicked = false;

        public Stone()
        {
            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.Stone_Paint);
            this.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.Size = new Size(40, 40);
        }

        public void setLocation(int x, int y)
        {
            Point loc = new Point(x, y);
            this.Location = loc;
        }

        public void stone_Click(object sender, EventArgs a)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;

            if (clicked == true)
            {
                pen.Color = Color.Black;
                Invalidate();
                clicked = false;
                Console.WriteLine(clicked);
            }

            else if (clicked == false && pen.Color == Color.Black)
            {
                pen.Color = Color.White;
                Invalidate();
                clicked = true;
                Console.WriteLine(clicked);
            }
        }

        public void Stone_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs b)
        {
            b.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, 10, 10, 19, 19);
        }

        public Pen getPen()
        {
            return pen;
        }

        public void setClick(bool bl)
        {
            bl = clicked;
        }
    }
}
```

Code Win Form Class:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Solo
{
    public partial class Win : Form
    {
        Button okBut = new Button();
        Label txt = new Label();

        public Win()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Text = "U hebt Gewonnen!!!";
            this.BackColor = Color.Green;
            this.ForeColor = Color.White;
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

            okBut.BackColor = Color.White;
            okBut.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            okBut.Size = new Size(90, 25);
            okBut.Location = new Point(140, 240);
            okBut.Text = "OK";
            okBut.Click += new EventHandler(this.okBut_Click);

            txt.Text = "U hebt Gewonnen!!!";
            txt.Location = new Point(20, 100);
            txt.Size = new Size(400, 100);
            txt.Font = new Font("Arial", 25.0f, FontStyle.Bold);

            this.Controls.Add(okBut);
            this.Controls.Add(txt);
        }

        public void okBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is enough information.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post only code related to your problem and specify problem more precisely. Describe what is wrong with your current appoach

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to check if all the buttons on the board are white except one.

Comment: Looks like adding a little formatting made your question clear enough to get 4 answers in 10 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you remember if a stone has been clicked in the `Stone.clicked` variable.

Expose this variable so it can be accessed from outside the `Stone` class:

```
public class Stone : Button {
    public bool Clicked { get; private set; }
}
```

Then you can check the overall state after every click by inspecting the `Stone[] st`. I do this using LINQ:

```
bool onlyOneNotClicked = st.Count(s => s.Clicked) == st.Length -1;
```

**Edit**

As suggested by prof1990, the following is more readable:

```
bool onlyOneNotClicked = st.Count(s => s.!Clicked) == 1;
```

Also, making the setter of `Stone.Clicked` private makes sure that nobody can mess with the state from outside.

Comment: very elegant but using `st.Count(s => !s.Clicked) == 1` would be even clearer

Answer (score 1):

So, actually, you want to check `Stone`s, not `Button`s; with a help of *Linq* you can put it like this:

> How to check if all the buttons are white and only one is black?

```
   var blackCount = Controls
     .OfType<Stone>()
     .Count(stone => stone.getPen().Color == System.Drawing.Color.Black);

   if (blackCount == 1) {
     ...
   }
```

**P.S.** As a matter of fact, I don't like the condition `stone.getPen().Color == System.Drawing.Color.Black` which mixes UI (color of the button; what if you repaint the buttons into gray and yellow?) and logic (taken and live stones). You, probably, should change the condition into something like `stone => stone.Clicked`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the stone color a public property, and check the win condition in your `Form1` class after every click. 
The condition being:

```
st.Count(x => x.Color == Color.Black) == 1 &&
st.Count(x => x.Color == Color.White) == st.Count() - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a stone which hasn't been clicked remains black..

```
        int numBlack = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < st.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!st[i].Clicked) numBlack++;
        }
```

This can be run each time a stone is clicked so that you can check how many stones are still black